# Return latest value within multiple single date rows

Tags: google-sheets, finance

So, the issue: I have a daily finances table, where I insert all incomings and outgoings every day. Every transaction creates a new line within the spreadsheet, so many rows will begin with the same date.
What I need to do for a different spreadsheet (within the same doc) is to return the final sum on both bank accounts at the end of the day, so the latest added entry within the range of rows starting with the specific date (screenshot example: return the value from cell G20 for the 5th of January).

I've tried a rather simple version VLOOKUP, but it just returns randomly correct or incorrect results.

Here's a screenshot to explain the situation:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UabxW.png]

Comment: are dates always sorted in ascending order?

Comment: Yes, always in ascending

Comment: Did any of the solutions provided below work for your use-case? @hdurr

Answer (score 1):

Vlookup should work if the dates are in order, plz try

```
=vlookup(I2,{A2:A,G2:G},2,true)
```

[image]

Comment: Ummm my Google Sheets doesn't seem to like the coma within {}, that is it refuses to recognize the two ranges within the {}.

Comment: Nevermind, that was a comas and semicolons issue, but now it returns "vlookup evaluates to an out of bounds range"

Comment: I don't know, have you tried changing all the commas to semi-colons in your locale? The alternative would be =vlookup(I2,A2:G,7,true)

Comment: I changed the commas to semicolons before my last post already, but now it returns "vlookup evaluates to an out of bounds range".

Comment: I think it should be this in your locale =vlookup(I2;{A2:A\G2:G};2;true)  This works for me if I change locale to Germany, for example.

Comment: Huh, OK. I'm currently in Finnish locale, because for some reason Sheets doesn't deem it necessary to create an Estonian one. But thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Annoying not to recognise Estonia. But anyway, Finnish would be the same as German as far as the formula is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT({A2:A, G2:G, ROW(A2:A)}, 3, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 9^9, 2)
```